# Setting height of absolutely positioned link where display:block

Tags: html, css

Hoping for some advice around a CSS issue - I have a layout where I'm absolutely positioning link text above a background image, but cannot get the link to expand to the height of the container (in IEx, works fine in Chrome)

```
<div>
    <img />
    <a />            
</div>
```

The containing div has a background colour, and the image has its opacity reduced - on hovering the image, the opacity reduces further, leaking more of the background color. At the same time, the opacity of the link changes from 0 to 100. I'm using a few CSS transitions as well, just to prettify it.

I know that positioning the link absolutely removes it from the flow, so setting height to 100% won't work, but shouldn't I be able to set it explicitly? Doing so works in Chrome but not IE. Problem is related to the image, as the link behaves correctly if it is removed.

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/thSCJ/8/ (includes just enough detail to highlight my problem. In IE, hovering the top left of the image reveals the link. In Chrome, any hover on the image reveals the link).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the anchor text to have the same width and height of the background?

Comment: The anchor text should just flow within the containing div - the linked area thought should match the dimensions of the div. I'm going to try moving the image to a css background, then setting the color on the container, with a low opacity which increases on hover. Should have the same effect, but might solve the other problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `<a>` tag wrapping the image and the text:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6kpJ562NTt7Vkya4ocQ3Aq7mVqNB04ccB9XNCr-b4mPdYU6Y5Yg" width=200 height=200/>
    <span>Link text</span>
</a>​
```

Here is the CSS:

```
a {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#cccccc;
}

a:hover > span {
    display: inline;
}

span {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    color:red;      
}
```

​

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thSCJ/12/

Comment: Still has the same result - in IE, hovering the image displays the link, but the linked area is the text only, whereas it needs to be the same dimension as the image.

Comment: This is pretty much how I've gone about it - I don't change display on hover, since I'm using transitions. Will mark this as correct as it's more complete than @hellohellosharp

Comment: I'm sorry, @hellohellosharp, I wasn't aware of that. I changed my answer after he further explained the question.

Comment: Not a problem, I'll get it over it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the opacity, simple change the `font-size` property and put the entire thing in the `<a>` tag.

[See this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/thSCJ/11/)